# conditionalParentLabel Signature Tab

Tags: docusignapi

I would like to set a tag (date/time) to only display if the user actually signs the document.
When defining a Signature tab (signHereTabs) as the conditionalParentLabel, I get the following error:
CONDITIONALTAB_HAS_INVALID_PARENT
A conditional tab references an invalid parent. Parent label must match another tab. Only one parent allowed. Signature tabs may not be parent tabs.
But if I set the the signature tab as "optional" it does work as intended - it only shows the field after the user signs.
Is there a way to achieve this on a "required" signature tab?

Following is the "tabs" json section.  tabLabel of the signature is "signerOtAuthsig".  Only when that is signed, I want the tabLabel "datetime_signed_auth" to show.

```
"tabs": {
    "dateSignedTabs": [

        {
            "anchorString": "Auth_Date_Time",
            "anchorXOffset": "-2",
            "anchorYOffset": "-4",
            "ConditionalParentLabel": "signerOtAuthsig",
            "ConditionalParentValue": "On",
            "font": "Tahoma",
            "fontSize": "Size10",
            "bold": "true",
            "name": "Date",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "tabLabel": "datetime_signed_auth"
        }
    ],
    "fullNameTabs": [
        {
            "anchorString": "Ot_Auth_Name",
            "anchorXOffset": "-2",
            "anchorYOffset": "-4",
            "font": "Tahoma",
            "fontSize": "Size10",
            "bold": "true",
            "name": "Full Name Electronically",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "tabLabel": "Full Name Electronically"
        }
    ],
    "signHereTabs": [
        {
            "anchorString": "Auth_Signature",
            "optional": "false",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "scaleValue": 1,
            "tabLabel": "signerOtAuthsig"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: can you please share your code?

Comment: Thank you.  I added thr json in the original post.

Comment: maybe you can change the order? so that the parent tab is first? perhaps it process them in the order they are in JSON

Comment: if you want to put Signature as optional then why you want SignatureTab to be required? Because if you want SignatureTab as required then signer will not be able to finish the envelope until he/she puts his/her signature. And Optional SignatureTab can fix your conditional Date/time tab clause as well.

Comment: Inbar, I changed the order of the tabs but it didn't help.  Same error message.

Comment: Amit, I DO need it to be required.  Correct, if it's optional, the conditional date/time does work as intended.  But I would like the conditional tab to work fine when the signature is required.

Comment: @NF, let me rephrase it. If Signature tab is required then envelope is never marked completed until the signer finishes signing, and if you put DateSigned Tab on the envelope then it will always have the latest date/time when envelope was last opened and completed. So hiding date/time till the time Required Signature is not signed is not giving me a valid reason to put that condition. So please share why you want date signed tab to be hidden?

Comment: The reason is that we show the date/time sign before the user actually signs it.  It doesn't look right.  They didn't sign it yet.

Comment: But it is not burnt on the document till the time Finish button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

You can add the same recipient twice. They would have to "sign" twice, but the second time would only have the date tab and they would just have to open it and click "Complete". 
This approach is one of two ways I can think of to not show the date before they sign. The other one is to use a text tab and they fill the date. That latter approach mimic more of the old way we signed on paper.